# Windows service won't start until after I run it with my credentials first

Tags: windows, service

When I create a new windows service on a machine, I have to run the EXE, which runs under my account, before I can actually start the service with its "real" credentials.

I'm using the `sc` commands to create, config, and start the service:

```
sc create "Presto Self Updating Service Host" binPath= "C:\Program Files (x86)\Presto\Presto Self Updating Service Host\SelfUpdatingServiceHost.exe"

sc config "Presto Self Updating Service Host" obj= "serviceAccount" password= "pw" start= auto

sc start "Presto Self Updating Service Host"
```

The service won't start until I go into the service properties and enter the password manually. That causes the service account to get "logon as a service rights." I've given up on trying to automate that. So, after I do that part, I start the service and I get an error message:

[image]

There is nothing in the event log about a failure. So what I do is run the EXE myself. That works. Then I close the EXE and start the service (with the serviceAccount user) and then it works. Any idea why it running it as me first would finally cause it to work as the other user?

Comment: Impossible to say, really.  I recommend adding writes to the event log to your code so that you can narrow down the point at which it is failing.

Comment: There used to be a MS application called `ntrights.exe` that manipulated user rights; not sure if it is still available.  Or you can use the `LsaAddAccountRights` function.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx